# Changing name of Resource Group

Tags: azure, terraform

The following code successfully deploys 2 x log analytic workspaces in different regions in azure in their own region based resource groups

How would I go about changing the name of both Resource Groups (p-ause-lp-management-rg & p-auea-lp-management-rg) and LAWs (p-ause-lp-management-log & p-auea-lp-management-log)

Structure would look like:

```
p-ause-lp-management-rg
  >p-ause-lp-management-log

p-auea-lp-management-rg
  >p-auea-lp-management-log
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "workspaces" {
  for_each = var.workspaces

  name     = each.key
  location = each.value.location
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "workspaces" {
  for_each = var.workspaces

  name                = each.key
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.workspaces[each.key].name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = each.value.retention_in_days
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "workspaces" {
  type = map(object({
    location          = string
    retention_in_days = number
  }))
  default = {
    workspace1 = {
      location          = "australiasoutheast"
      retention_in_days = 30
    }
    workspace2 = {
      location          = "australiaeast"
      retention_in_days = 30
    }
    # Add more workspaces as needed
  }
}
```

**outputs.tf**

```
# Define outputs
output "workspace_ids" {
  value = values(azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspaces)[*].id
}

output "workspace_names" {
  value = values(azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspaces)[*].name
}

output "resource_group_ids" {
  value = values(azurerm_resource_group.workspaces)[*].id
}

output "resource_group_names" {
  value = values(azurerm_resource_group.workspaces)[*].name
}

output "resource_group_locations" {
  value = values(azurerm_resource_group.workspaces)[*].location
}
```

Comment: cant we destroy the old one and create the new one with the new name @Cyborganizer any blockers you're facing, I'm asking this because changing keys in Terraform configurations is interpreted as a request to destroy the old resource and create a new one with the new key. This behavior is intrinsic to how Terraform manages its state and resources.

Comment: @VinayB This is a greenfields environment, so yeah we can destroy it completely and start fresh. Any way to variablising the workspaces ie Workspace1 would become ${deploymentEnvironment}-${locationIdentifier}-${companyPrefix}-management-log then we can pass the vairables to the resource groups, so the RG would become  ${deploymentEnvironment}-${locationIdentifier}-${companyPrefix}-RG. I'm open to other suggestions

Comment: What is `var.resource_groups`?

Comment: var.resource_groups was a typo, it's actually var.workspaces. Corrected it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried Changing the name of the Resource Group in a dynamic format so that we can use it for different environments and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

Using variables to dynamically generate names for your workspaces and resource groups is a great approach if you're working in a dedicated environment. This makes your Terraform configurations more flexible and reusable across different environments, locations, or organizational structures.

I use variables to specify the deployment environment, the location identifier, and the company prefix. Then, I combine these variables to create the names of the workspaces and resource groups dynamically.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "deployment_environment" {
  description = "Deployment environment (e.g., dev, prod)"
  type        = string
}

variable "company_prefix" {
  description = "Company prefix for naming resources"
  type        = string
}

variable "locations" {
  description = "Map of location identifiers to Azure region names"
  type = map(object({
    region = string
  }))
  default = {
    ause = {
      region = "east us"
    },
    auea = {
      region = "east us2"
    }
  }
}

variable "retention_in_days" {
  description = "Number of days to retain logs"
  type        = number
  default     = 30
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  for_each = var.locations

  name     = "${var.deployment_environment}-${each.key}-${var.company_prefix}-RG"
  location = each.value.region
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "law" {
  for_each = var.locations

  name                = "${var.deployment_environment}-${each.key}-${var.company_prefix}-management-log"
  location            = each.value.region
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[each.key].name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = var.retention_in_days
}

output "resource_group_names" {
  value = { for k, v in azurerm_resource_group.rg : k => v.name }
}

output "log_analytics_workspace_names" {
  value = { for k, v in azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law : k => v.name }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks @vinay that worked.  Can you break down the output value step by step. I'm struggling to understand what it's doing. value = { for k, v in azurerm_resource_group.rg : k => v.name }

Comment: { ... }: Defines a map (key-value pairs). & 
for k, v in azurerm_resource_group.rg: Iterates over the azurerm_resource_group.rg map, where k is each key and v is each value (the resource groups). & 
: k => v.name: For each iteration, creates an entry in the output map where the key is k (the same as the original key) and the value is v.name (the name of the resource group).
@Cyborganizer hope this is clear for you how it works.